# Why can't I see the pop-up card for the adsense tag on hover?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I kept seeing this question: [Responsive Adsense ad on mobile displaying huge ad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520300/responsive-adsense-ad-on-mobile-displaying-huge-ad)

Hovering over the adsense tag does not pop up the normal watch/ignore dialog. If I click on the tag and select ignore, the tag is briefly shown in my ignored list. However, if I go back to the question list, questions tagged with adsense still appear. If I check the ignored tag box, the adsense tag has disappeared.

Addendum:

I used the add form in the ignore box to add the tag. Now if I search for `[adsense]` the "unignore tag" button cannot be selected.

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce this issue.  I don't see any backend errors related to tag pages, and it looks like you're successfully ignored the tag.  I'm suspecting there's a JavaScript error. Does hovering over other tags bring up the dialog?  Are there any errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: Nothing in the console. I do have ublock origin, privacy badger and noscript (loading stackoverflow.com, ajax.googleapis.com and sstatic.net). Looks like it is ublock origin that is causing the issue although I can't see anything particularly different about pages with the tag and those without.

Comment: Note, this is also affecting the [tag:google-analytics] tag. Possibly more.

Comment: @TylerH This exact issue has been reported earlier today:‌ [Tag popup doesn't show on some tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348913/289905).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like the problem is caused by a conflict with my adblocker, 'uBlock Origin', which uses 'EasyList' with blacklist rules like:

```
/adsense/*
```

A minimal change to fix the issue seems to be add to the whitelist:

```
@@||stackoverflow.com/tags/*
```

Comment: Maybe the adblocker is coded to behave differently when it encounters the string "adsense"?

Comment: The specific issue here is that UBlock is using EasyList which has a rule filtering `/adsense/*` requests.  This catches our XHR requests like `/tags/adsense/popup` and `/tags/adsense/prefs`.  The correct course of action here is to disable the content blocker when changing your tag preferences, or to use the tag preference editor in the sidebar.

Comment: Same goes for AdBlockPlus with default settings. Who is currating those lists? This rule is kinda stupid, the currator should know ahead that it denies many legit requests.

Comment: It's in: https://github.com/easylist/easylist/blob/master/easylist/easylist_general_block.txt

Comment: I opened a issue on easylist https://github.com/easylist/easylist/issues/2820